# How to impliment SASLMechanism in Android using smack 4.1.4

Tags: android

How to implement:
**public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism {
    private static final String NAME = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";**

```
private String apiKey = "";
private String accessToken = " ";
public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void authenticateInternal(CallbackHandler cbh) throws SmackException {
}

@Override
protected byte[] getAuthenticationText() throws SmackException {
    return null;

}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPriority() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void checkIfSuccessfulOrThrow() throws SmackException {

}

@Override
protected SASLMechanism newInstance() {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the problem that you are having?